# Sorting Tables With php and shorty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, formatting

I am doing some work on a business site that uses php and smarty. Right now we have an invoice  being sent to an orders department and need a way to systematicly find items on a shelf.

I have all of the fields set up, but I don't know how to sort to html table rows using php. It uses a for each statement to make a row for each item ordered.

IS there a way to do this with php with or without a combination of smarty? I'm still new to it, and any help would be appreciated.

I found the query.

```
$products = func_query("SELECT $sql_tbl[order_details].itemid, $sql_tbl[products].*, $sql_tbl[products_lng_current].*, $sql_tbl[extra_field_values].value, $sql_tbl[order_details].*, IF($sql_tbl[products].productid IS NULL, 'Y', '') as is_deleted, IF($sql_tbl[order_details].product = '', $sql_tbl[products_lng_current].product, $sql_tbl[order_details].product) as product $fields FROM $sql_tbl[order_details] LEFT JOIN $sql_tbl[products] ON $sql_tbl[order_details].productid = $sql_tbl[products].productid LEFT JOIN $sql_tbl[products_lng_current] ON $sql_tbl[products_lng_current].productid=$sql_tbl[products].productid $join WHERE $sql_tbl[order_details].orderid='$orderid' ORDER BY $sql_tbl[extra_field_values].value desc);
```

I added the order by, but, it breaks the page.

Comment: Assuming these orders are retrieved from a database, you ought to sort them in the query's `ORDER BY` rather than making PHP do it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you're retrieving the data. If it's coming from a database, you should just be able to include the `ORDER BY` clause in your query, and everything will be just great.

Failing that, you mention you're outputting inside a `foreach` loop, so perhaps the data's already stored in an array from an external source. In that case, you could try reading up on the PHP function [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Check out the jQuery plugin, 'DataTables':
http://datatables.net/

Finally, if you absolutley have no other alternative than to do this with the DOM, you might want to check out 'DataTables'. It is a plugin for jQuery which allows `<table>` elements to be sorted using a custom algorithm (and you can specify which fields the user can sort by, etc.) It shouldn't be too painful to integrate this into an existing Smarty template, either.

Comment: I found the query but when I do an ORDER by it breaks the page. I addeed to the get cause as well. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you show your query? Adding `ORDER BY` certainly shouldn't break anything - unless it's been added incorrectly.

Comment: If that's a verbatim copy of the entire line, you're missing the ending `"` (see before `;`).

Comment: A derp, thanks. I just uploaded it. The page populates now, but the table doesn't add the product rows anymore.

Comment: That's not related to the `ORDER BY`, or indeed the original question ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I I just got the error message, I sorted by a table that doesn't exist. I probably just referenced it wrong. I'm going to get some coffee and battle this thing some more.